# I have a dropdown list and i want it to show the selected value on. the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, gravityforms

I want something like when I select a value on the drop-down list, that particular value has to show on my submit button. Please check the link below for what I mean
https://www.elefant-tours.de/ueber-uns/reiseanmeldung/?wetu_id=15FAC4B2-C939-4179-918D-E3140BA3177E

Comment: This looks like a DOM manipulation job with js.  Can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: I can write that func for you.. you need to embed it inside gravity form - "there is an easy way to add custom Javascript to your Gravity Forms that only loads when the form is rendered. Just copy-and-paste your desired snippet into the robust editor on your Form Settings and you’re golden."

Comment: Well can you please add the function for me

Answer (score 1):

Example of that behavior with jquery.
You need **to match the select id**
and also insert a span tag inside the button with a matching class

**Live example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/1qjvtc86/

**From gravityforms site:**

> there is an easy way to add custom Javascript to your Gravity Forms
> that only loads when the form is rendered. Just copy-and-paste your
> desired snippet into the robust editor on your Form Settings and
> you’re golden.

```
<div>
    <select id="picker">
        <option value="5">5 items</option>
        <option value="4">4 items</option>
        <option value="3">3 items</option>
        <option value="2">2 items</option>
        <option value="1">1 items</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <button>user picked <span class="pickedAmount">1</span> items</button>
</div>


<!-- copy this into gravity form -->
<script>
// picker - is the ID of the select
// pickedAmount - is the CLASS of the span 
jQuery(function($){
 
    $('#picker').on('change', function() {
        $('.pickedAmount').text($(this).val());
    })

});
</script>
<!-- copy this into gravity form -->
```

Comment: That worked thank you, but how do I add hyperlinks for each seperate element that when i click the submit button it will redirect to a different page

Comment: But... doesn't the button submit that form? its a gravity form inside a Wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

**Your JavaScript solution is**:

```js
function my_fun(obj){
   alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="my_fun(this)">
   <option>item one(1)</option>
   <option>item two(2)</option>
   <option>item three(3)</option>
   <option>item four(4)</option>
   <option>item five(5)</option>
</select>
```